# Difference between src and require or include (path)

Tags: php, html, path, relative-path, src

From any file on the website if I want to call an image posted on /ico I do:

```
$arrow = "/ico/arrow.png";
```

without do any sort of ../ico/ect. or ./ico/etc.

Now if I want to include a file header.php saved in /test:

```
<?php
include "/test/header.php";
```

or

```
require "/test/header.php";
```

or

```
require_once "/test/header.php";
?>
```

This won't work. I have to specify the path with ../ or ./.

I cannot understand this difference!

Thank you!

Comment: Resource references in HTML/CSS are relative to the current document. In PHP paths are relative to the current directory, or to the filesystem root if you start them with `/`.

Comment: Ok for the PHP. But for the HTML: if my document is in /folder1/folder2/document.php and I call arrow.php with the /ico/arrow.png path I have arrow.png displayed!

Comment: Try without first `/`. I have same issue on my server. Try like `include("test/header.php");`

Comment: Absolute paths for resources are resolved to the website base, the DOCUMENT_ROOT.

Answer (score 3):

Image sources and link hrefs are evaluated by the client (browser). This means they are relative to:

- The web root (if the URL starts with a `/`). For the purposes of this answer, this can more easily be described as: your domain. If you are on http://www.yourpage.com/folder1/folder2/file.php and you reference `/img/arrow.png`, then it is assumed that you mean http://yourpage.com/img/arrow.png
- The current directory (if the URL doesn't start with a `/`, or starts with `./`). If you are on http://www.yourpage.com/folder1/folder2/file.php and you reference `img/arrow.png`, then it is assumed that you mean http://yourpage.com/folder1/folder2/img/arrow.png

Includes, on the other hand, are evaluated by the server. This means that they are relative to:

- The root of the filesystem (if the path starts with a `/`)
- The current working directory of the script (if the path doesn't start with `/`, or starts with `./`)

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand.
So for php it is more advisable to use the path relative to the current working directory, so if the ISP changes something, all will work again, am I right?

Comment: That's correct. In PHP it's advisable to always use relative paths. This allows you to move your application around wherever you feel necessary without changing any code. Or, define a `BASE_DIR` constant at the beginning of your application and use it for all includes.